# Solving Quadratic Matrix Equation involving Hadamard/Element-wise Product?

Tags: linear-algebra, positive-semidefinite, hadamard-product

I have the following equation:

$$x^T M x = (x \circ b)^T P (x \circ b) $$

where

- $x, b \in \mathbb{R}^D$ are vectors
- $M, P \in \mathbb{R}^{D \times D}$ are matrices
- $b, P$ are known
- $\circ$ denotes the element-wise (Hadamard) product)
- The equation holds for all $x$.

How can I solve this equation for $M$?

If it helps, I know that M and P are both symmetric positive semi-definite matrices.

Comment: Note that $b \circ x = B x$ where $B$ is diagonal with $B_{ii} = b_i$.

Comment: Thank you! That makes this so much more obvious. Should I delete my question?

Comment: @WimC I can delete, or if you want credit for giving a helpful suggestion, you can write an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: Better to write your *own* answer and accept it. That is perfectly fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As WimC pointed out in the comments above, $x \cdot b$ can be written as $xB$ or $Bx$ where $B=diag(b)$. Consequently:

$$x^T M x = x^T B^T P B x$$

and therefore

$$M = B^T P B$$

Comment: It is worth noting that this solution is not unique. Let $y$ be any vector which is orthogonal to $x,$ i.e. $\,x^Ty=0,$ then
$\;M'=M+yy^T\;$
is also a solution to the equation.